# Проблема в обучении агента Unity MLAgents

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

У меня есть сцена с трассой и машиной, и я хочу чтобы машина научилась сама проходить трассу. Всё работает правильно, только машина странно обучается. Такое чувство, что она не использует ray perception sensor 3d. На сцене есть чекпоинты, если машина проходит их в правильном направлении, то она получает награду +0.01 , а если в неправильном то -0.01. Скрипт агента:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Unity.MLAgents;
using Unity.MLAgents.Actuators;
using Unity.MLAgents.Sensors;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;
using System;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;

public class Car : Agent
{
    [SerializeField] private TrackCheckpoints trackCheckpoints;
    [SerializeField] private Transform spwanPosition;

    private MSVehicleControllerFree carDriver; //контроллер машины
    private MSSceneControllerFree sceneController; //контроллер сцены, нужен для вывода скорости
    public GameObject scene;

    
    public Text distance_text;


    double distanceTravelled = 0;
    Vector3 lastPosition;
    
    //в корутине даём награду за расстоянии которое проехала машина
    IEnumerator distance_reward()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);
            AddReward((float)(0.001 * distanceTravelled));
            distanceTravelled = 0;
        }
    }

    public void Awake()
    {
        carDriver = GetComponent<MSVehicleControllerFree>();
        lastPosition = transform.position;
        sceneController = scene.GetComponent<MSSceneControllerFree>();
        StartCoroutine(distance_reward());
    }



    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //штрафуем машину за низкую скорость
        if (sceneController.car_speed < 10) {
            AddReward(-0.00001f);
        }

        //изменяем дистацию которая проехала машина
        if (sceneController.car_speed >= 0) {
            distanceTravelled += Vector3.Distance(transform.position, lastPosition);
        }
        else if (sceneController.car_speed < 0) {
            distanceTravelled -= Vector3.Distance(transform.position, lastPosition);
        }
        lastPosition = transform.position;
        distanceTravelled = Math.Round(distanceTravelled, 3);
        distance_text.text = "Distance: " + distanceTravelled;

        //награждаем машину за скорость
        AddReward((float)(0.000002 * sceneController.car_speed));
    }

    public override void OnEpisodeBegin()
    {
        //спавн машины
        transform.position = spwanPosition.position + new Vector3 (Random.Range(-1f,+1f), 0, Random.Range(-1f, +1f));
        transform.forward = spwanPosition.forward;
        trackCheckpoints.ResetCheckpoints(transform);
        carDriver.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = Vector3.zero;
        
        //сбрасываем дистанцию которая прошла машина
        lastPosition = transform.position;
        distanceTravelled = 0;
        StartCoroutine(distance_reward());
    }
    public override void CollectObservations(VectorSensor sensor)
    {
        Vector3 checkpointForward = trackCheckpoints.GetNextCheckpoint(transform).transform.forward;
        float directionDot = Vector3.Dot(transform.forward, checkpointForward);
        
        //передаем на вход ИИ направление следующего чекпоинта, скорости машины, дистанции которую прошла в течении 1 секунды
        sensor.AddObservation(directionDot);
        sensor.AddObservation(sceneController.car_speed);
        sensor.AddObservation((float)distanceTravelled);
    }
    public override void OnActionReceived(ActionBuffers actions)
    {
        float forwardAmount = 0f;
        float turnAmount = 0f;

        switch (actions.DiscreteActions[0])
        {
            case 0: forwardAmount = 0f; break;
            case 1: forwardAmount = +1f; break;
            case 2: forwardAmount = -1f; break;
        }
        switch (actions.DiscreteActions[1])
        {
            case 0: turnAmount = 0f; break;
            case 1: turnAmount = -1f; break;
            case 2: turnAmount = +1f; break;
        }
        sceneController.Update_Controls(forwardAmount, turnAmount);
        carDriver.GetComponent<MSVehicleControllerFree>().Update_Controls(forwardAmount, turnAmount);
        
        //штрафуем машину каждый шаг
        AddReward(-0.000007f);
    }
    public override void Heuristic(in ActionBuffers actionsOut)
    {
        int forwardAction = 0;
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Keypad8)) forwardAction = 1;
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Keypad5)) forwardAction = 2;

        int turnAction = 0;
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Keypad4)) turnAction = 1;
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Keypad6)) turnAction = 2;

        ActionSegment<int> discreteActions = actionsOut.DiscreteActions;
        discreteActions[0] = forwardAction;
        discreteActions[1] = turnAction;
    }
    
    //даём отрицательную награду если машина врезалась в стену
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.TryGetComponent<Wall>(out Wall wall))
        {
            AddReward(-0.01f);
            EndEpisode();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Настройки агента] [image]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Забыл упомянуть, что обучаю ИИ на процессоре. Может ли быть в этом проблема?

Comment: Функция оценки разреженая. Если машинка застряла между чекпоинтами, она ничему не учится. Поменяйте функцию на "какое расстояние преодолела машина за фиксированный промежуток времени". Обучение пойдёт быстрее.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy с этим проблем не было. Обычно машина сразу едет вперёд или назад. Только вот поворачивать долго учится. А как реализовать функцию которую вы написали, не очень понимаю. Просто ещё беспокоит то, что машина сначала пытается проходить трассу правильно, а потом проходит в обратном направлении, что даёт ей отрицательную награду.

Comment: Вы понимаете что значит "разреженная"? Если вы хотите чтобы агент учился и быстро, вы должны поощрять каждое небольшое улучшение и штрафовать каждое небольшое ухудшение. Ваша текущая функция не обладает этим свойством. Обучение носит случайных характер.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Реализовал вашу функцию "какое расстояние преодолела машина за фиксированный промежуток времени". Теперь машине выдаётся награда за расстояние которое она проехала в течении 1 секунды. Но есть проблема, что в начале обучения машина практически не поворачивает, то есть едет прямо в стену.

Comment: Штрафуйте за удары в стену.

Comment: Какая информация доступна машине во время движения?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Машину за удары в стену штрафую. Машина знает свою скорость, направление следующего чекпоинта и расстояние которое прошла в течение 1 секунды. Обновил скрипт выше и добавил комментарии

Comment: То есть машина слепая? Стен она не видит пока в них не ударится? Если так, то трудно вам будет заставить её ездить по трассе.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy ну так я добавил на неё 2 сенсора, которые выпускают лучи, они на скриншотах. И нужно ли их в скрипте их как-то прописывать?